# Fluent Nhibernate and MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to do a MVC project where i want to use fluent nhibernate. gonna use sql. unfortunately i am confused about how to even start it. i found no tutorials in the net. i need help in organizing my project.thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a series on my blog where I build a forum application using asp.net mvc and fluent nhibernate. You can check out one of the earlier posts and download the source code. Here is the link to the series: http://mattias-jakobsson.net/archive.aspx#Jakobsson-forum.

Comment: i think i am trying to do the same...thanks...will check it out...:)

Comment: The Forum Application link is dead.

Comment: Yes, I know. Sorry, that was my old blog engine. The link is now updated. I'm afraid I never got to finish the application though.

Answer (score 3):

[Sharp architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/MainPage.ashx) can be helpful. You can base your application on it. It contains MVC and nHibernate and handles many problems that you will have during application development. It is solid base for every MVC app.

Comment: i checked it out earlier...have you tried it? i could find no reviews for it that encouraged me to go for it and experiment...

Comment: I've started with S#arp without any experience with NHibernate/ASP.NET MVC/IoC/etc, very little jQuery, good ASP.NET and databases. It was very easy to start and use, and I enjoy it even more now. It does include tutorials, both sample project and wiki, and more files here: http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture/files

Comment: queen3: You gave recently an example of an application built with Sharp architecture. Could you give us the name again?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Who Can Help Me?](http://jamesbroo.me/introducing-who-can-help-me-a-new-sample-mvc-web-application/), which is an example site put together by EMC that uses many of the big OSS projects out there today. Specifically of interest: MVC + Sharp Architecture + Fluent NHibernate.

[James Broome](http://jamesbroo.me/) has also written plenty of stuff about using all the technologies used in the above on [his EMC blog](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesbroome/default.aspx).